# Injecting floor database dependency through GETX is not working : Flutter

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, instance, flutter-getx, flutter-floor

I am new at using Getx for state management. I am trying to inject the dependency of my DB instance in main by Getx through initial binding I am using the floor database. can anyone help me with this. where I went wrong?

this is how my register function looks like

> ```
> void registerdbInstance() {
>   Get.lazyPut(<AppDatabase>() async =>
>       {await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('app_database.db').build()});
> }
> ```

this is how my main app widget looks like

> ```
>  @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return GetMaterialApp(
>       title: appName,
>       initialBinding: BindingsBuilder.put(() => registerdbInstance),
>       theme: ThemeData(
>         fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
>         backgroundColor: sdWhiteColor,
>         colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
>             .copyWith(primary: sdPrimaryColor, secondary: sdSecondaryColor),
>       ),
>       getPages: routeList,
>       home: ServiceDeskHome(),
>     );
> ```

**initialBinding: BindingsBuilder.put(() => registerdbInstance),**

this is how I am trying to access this dependency

> var db = Get.find();

The problem is that Getx is not able to find the dependency.

**"AppDatabase" not found. You need to call "Get.put(AppDatabase())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>AppDatabase())"**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I initialized it in this way.
it will initialize when the app starts, you can use it later  anywhere by simply calling Get.find()

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Get.putAsync<AppDatabase>(permanent: true, () async {
    final db = await $FloorAppDatabase
        .databaseBuilder('todotask.db')
        .build();
    return db;
  });
  await GetStorage.init();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i recall corectly when you are working with databases in getx you have to do it asynchronously and use **Get.putAsync** if you want to register an asynchronous instance ([LINK](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/dependency-management/instancing-method#getputasync)). I would consider using fenix parameter as well.

Comment: i already tried with putAsync.. not working

Comment: thanks, I register asynchronously and I created a DB object in main(). I wanted to initiate as soon app started so it's behaving fine as  I want this instance to be. I remove it from binding.